# Como é que consigo apanhar e guardar este valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um programa grande demais para por aqui e por isso criei um fiddle para ilustrar o meu problema.

Eu quero apanhar e guardar numa variavel o `p`, mas o `alert` está sempre a mandar vazio. Podem ajudar-me sff?

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class = "middle_item">
        <a>
            <div id= "box">
                <div id= "header">
                    <p>1234567</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>

        </a>           
    </li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
var aqui = $("li .middle_item .header").text();
alert(aqui);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ufkoqeu8/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deves ter em conta que:

- deve ser sem espaço aqui: `li .middle_item` pois é o proprio elemento `li` que tem a classe `middle_item` e não descendente de.
- o `#` é o seletor de ID, deves então mudar o selector de classe `.` para `#`.

Repara ainda que uma vez que IDs são únicas então a parte `li.middle_item` é redundante.

Deve ficar então:

```
var aqui = $("#header p").text();
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v0ss1mkt/

Comment: Não é esse o fiddle. o fiddle correcto http://jsfiddle.net/ufkoqeu8/6/

Comment: @msm.oliveira ah, mudaste a pergunta...

Comment: @msm.oliveira então é isto que queres: http://jsfiddle.net/ufkoqeu8/7/

Comment: que erro estúpido da minha parte´. já percebi. estava a usar o ´.´ em vez de ´#´. Aquela ´div´ tem ´id´ e não ´class´

Comment: @msm.oliveira acontece a todos, bom ter outro par de olhos a ver às vezes :) Lembra-te que deve ser sem espaço aqui: `li .middle_item` e que o `#` é o seletor de ID.

Comment: ok. obrigado. se quiseres actualiza a resposta que eu a aceito

Comment: @msm.oliveira atualizei a resposta e vou apagar estes comentários aqui depois também.